# How to hide a text inside a Powerpoint slide using OpenXML SDK?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to hide a text inside a slide (or TextBox) by using OpenXML SDK. How Do I hide the text without the user seeing it?

I tried to set the opacity using `Drawing.Run` method but it doesn't support the HexCode having length greater than 6. The powerpoint shows the warning message to Repair the presentation after that.

The code I've tried is :

```
 Drawing.RgbColorModelHex rgbColorModelHex2 = new Drawing.RgbColorModelHex() { Val = "00FFFFFF" };
```

On my research there is a vanish property in `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing` for hiding text on Word but couldn't find vanish on powerpoint. Is there any similar property in powerpoint ? or else how do I hide a text ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Open XML Productivity Tool is included with the SDK. Make a pair of files in PowerPoint, one with the text showing and the other with the text hidden (use the Selection Pane to do this). Then use the Compare Files feature in the Productivity tool. The initial view will show the XML parts that have differences. Then click on the View Package Code to see automatically generated C# code that will help you figure out the correct syntax.

Another toolset that is very helpful with Open XML is Open XML Power Tools. Here's the NuGet page for it: [OpenXmlPowerTools 4.5.3.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenXmlPowerTools/)

Comment: Hi @john Thanks for the answer. Actually am  new to OpenXml SDK and PowerPoint Add-In. Using the Selection Pane I hide the text inside a TextBox but still the user can see the text by using the show all property . Can I avoid that ?

Thanks once again for the reply

Comment: Depending on your goal, you can add text to an object tag using VBA and read that text using VBA. Tags never display. Or you can make the text the same color as the shape it's in, which offers only minimal security. Or you could hide the text with the Selection Pane, then remove the Selection Pane option from the Ribbon. This last one is a lot of work, because you have to rebuild the Editing group on the Home tab.

Comment: Thanks @john. I figured out the differences and it works fine :)